# Flutter go_router with Provider that needs initial paramenters

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-go-router

i'm new to use Provider integrate with go_router in Flutter follow by MVVM pattern. Problem happen when my Provider class needs initial value in constructor.
Let's say we have 2 screens with its view models: `Screen1` with `ViewModel1` and `Screen2` with `ViewModel2`. The approach we normally see is that:

```
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => ViewModel1()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => ViewModel2()),
      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
```

But in my case, `ViewModel2` is a PDP screen and it needs an ID parameter (to call api get detail) which passed from `Screen1`, because of that, we can not init 2 Providers at the root of the app like above.

I've tried to refactor the structure a bit, instead of create Providers at the root of app, i create Provider (view model) when screen is open by creating a base class, like this:

```
abstract class BaseScreen<Vm extends BaseViewModel> extends StatelessWidget {
  Vm createViewModel();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(),
      child: ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (_) => createViewModel(),
        child: ...
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And 2 screens will extend this `BaseScreen` and 2 view models will extend `BaseViewModel`, like this:

```
class Screen2 extends BaseView<ViewModel2> {
  final int id;

  @override
  Screen2 createViewModel() => ViewModel2(id);

  ...
```

It's works fine at the beginning. But the issue happen, i cannot access the previos Provider in `ViewModel2` by using `context.read<ViewModel1>()`, it throw error cannot find Provider in widget tree.
So i've checked the widget tree, (which using go_router for navigation), and it's look similar to this:
[Widget Tree Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgDzW.png)
The outer screen is not wrap it's sub routes, all the screen is the same level, children of root, so that `context.read<ViewModel1>()` cannot find the previous Provider.

You guys have any solutions for this problem? Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. My solution was to get data from current app state and use it directly in the router like so:

```
GoRoute(
        path: 'touch-calibration',
        name: 'touch_calibration',
        builder: (context, state) => TouchCalibrationScreen(isFirstRun: state.queryParams['firstRun'] == 'true'),
      ),
```

Then to push route use `context.pushNamed()`.

Comment: thank you, but it's not what i mean :(